# Help with には and にとって

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I need help understanding why にとって cannot be used in this circumstance:

> その仕事は私｛には/*にとって｝出来ない。 ( `*` denotes unacceptable)

This is what I read:

> にとって cannot be used when it marks an experiencer or agent

But I get confused when this sentence is acceptable:

> これは我々にとって無視できない問題だ。

Isn't `我々` an agent? `我々` is the one who is doing the ignoring right? So what am I understanding wrongly?

Comment: I cannot answer exactly when にとって can be used, but it might be useful to compare these sentences with an _unacceptable_ case これは我々にとって無視できない。

Comment: I probably have to wait for sawa to come and rescue me for this one. I suspect it has to do with some things that にとって does syntactically that is different from には.

Comment: Also compare with これは我々にとって問題だ (acceptable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`にとって` 'As from the point of view of ' is a sentence modifier. The sentence has to be meaningful without it, and it implies that its truth depends on whose point of view it is described from.

> これは(無視できない)問題だ
> 'This is a(n) (unignorable) problem.'
>
> **我我にとって**、これは(無視できない)問題だ
> 'For us, this is a(n) (unignorable) problem.'
>
> これは、我我にとって、(無視できない)問題だ　　[`これは` can be moved to the front.]
> 'Regarding this, from the point of view of us, it is a(n) (unignorable) problem.'

`に` in question here is a dative case marker, which optionally marks the subject of the embedded clause of a potential verb.

> 我我がこれを無視する
> 'We ignore this.'
>
> [我我{が/**に**}これを無視]できる　[`する` is deleted before `できる` due to the irregularity of potential form.]
> 'It is possible that we ignore this.'
>
> これは、我我{が/**に**}無視できる　　[`これは` can be topicalized and moved to the front.]
> 'Regarding this, it is possible that we ignore it.'

As usual in Japanese, the subject can be omitted, and be understood implicitly:

> これは、(我我{が/**に**})無視できる
> 'It is possible that we ignore this.'

Attaching `にとって` to this sentence does not work semantically because the possibility is independent of the point of view.

> * 我我にとって、これは(我我{が/**に**})無視できる
> 　'For us, it is possible that we ignore this.'